# How to power on internal SD card reader from disk utility

Tags: sd-card, disk-utility

I have a Dell laptop (Inspiron-3521) which have an SD card slot.
I used this slot to install some images for my raspberry pi.
I wanted to test something and using the Ubuntu disk utility I powered it off  and now I can't turn it on again.
I tried to reinsert the card several times and it didn't work i also tried to reboot my system several times which also didn't work.
The SD card slot was working fine before powering it off and works just fine on windows.

Print screen of the power off option (i used a usb stick to recreate it): 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRWFw.jpg
lsusb and sudo fdisk -l results:
http://pastebin.com/9YviqwbN

Comment: **Close voters** , the question has sufficient clarity and is on topic on this site. Please retract your votes

Comment: @Serg If OP stated Disks utility was used to hide partition and not mount it then that would be clear and the answer would be to reuse the utility to mount it and unhide it. If the problem was clear there would have been an answer.

Comment: Doesn't work even after reboot ? @imoutidi

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix  problem doesn't have to be clear. Question has to be clear. There's tons of questions on site which have no clear solution, yet are open. sorry,  I believe this question must remain open

Comment: @Serg I'd like to see a screen capture of the "Ubuntu disk utility" with the "power off" button. I have no idea what is going on. Have you seen the screen before and the radio button or check box to "power off"? It's unclear to me and these quoted terms return nothing in google as if they are made up words...

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix you asked for the screen capture, here it is : http://imgur.com/a/ZrtgG

Comment: @Serg Doesn't look like a Ubuntu screen but I'll reverse my close vote. Can we delete all our comments to each other above?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix it is Ubuntu, with Ubuntu Kylin theme.

Comment: @Serg I thought Kylin was version created for China, but irregardless explains the different colours from vanilla Ubuntu Good call asking to leave the question open :).

Comment: @Serg  Edited my question with more information.

Comment: @imoutidi does this command help : `sudo bash -c 'echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan'  `

Comment: @Serg unfortunately not. I run the command and tried to reinstall the card and it didn't work and I also rebooted my system with no luck again.

Comment: on my laptop interestingly suspend-resume brought device back.